# change chatbot name in python

Tags: python, bots, chatbot, chatterbot

I created a chatbot and everything work but when I ask it "what's your name?" it supposed to respond "i'm **ReLebot**. ask me a math question, please." but it doesn't he actually respond "i'm **pybot**. ask me a math question, please.". What should I do?

```py
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
import pyttsx3 as tts;
from tkinter import *



my_bot = ChatBot(name='ReLebot', read_only=True,
          logic_adapters=
['chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation',
          'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch'])
small_talk = ['hi there!',
          'hi!',
          'how do you do?',
          'how are you?',
          'i\'m cool.',
          'fine, you?',
          'always cool.',
          'i\'m ok',
          'glad to hear that.',
          'i\'m fine',
          'glad to hear that.',
          'i feel awesome',
          'excellent, glad to hear that.',
          'not so good',
          'sorry to hear that.',
          'what\'s your name?',
          'i\'m ReLebot. ask me a math question, please.',
              'bye',
              'good bye it was nice talk']
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible if you add the below code in your myown.yml in custom folder .

```
categories:
- My Own 
- This is my own data
conversations:
- - what's your name?
  - i'm ReLebot.
```